# How to reference an instance variable in Python

Tags: python, oop, inheritance

I defined an instance variable in the **init**() method of a class and derived a new class from it. When I try to reference this variable from an instance of the secondary class, it seems it was not inherited.

This is the code:

```
company=Company()
person=Person()
task=Task()

print(company.get_attrs())

class Entity(Persistent):
    list_of_attrs=[]
    list_of_attrs_flag=False

    def __init__(self):
        attributes={}
        attributes_edition_flag={}
        if not type(self).list_of_attrs_flag:
            type(self).list_of_attrs=self.get_attrs_from_persistent()
            type(self).list_of_attrs_flag=True
            for attr in type(self).list_of_attrs:
                attributes[attr]=''
                attributes_edition_flag[attr]='false'

    def get_attrs(self):
        return(self.attributes)

class Company(Entity):
    def hello(self):
        print('hello')
```

This is the error I get:

```
MacBook-Pro-de-Hugo:Attractora hvillalobos$ virtual/bin/python3 control.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "control.py", line 7, in <module>
    print(company.get_attrs())
  File "/Users/hvillalobos/Dropbox/Code/Attractora/model.py", line 48, in get_attrs
    return(self.attributes)
AttributeError: 'Company' object has no attribute 'attributes'
```

It was working but I moved something (I guess), but I can't find what.
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your `__init__` method, you have to use `self.attributes`, not `attributes`.

Comment: This is correct. I have to mention, however, that instead of `type(self)` it is more correct to use `self.__class__` to access class attributes. I wonder why the OP is using the string 'false' instead of a boolean.

Comment: Thank you, @RobertB. I am using a string because it is a dictionary (the code is missing the index by mistake). Can I use data types other than strings as values of a dictionary?

Comment: Try it and find out.